# Estimate the distribution of your random sample average for different sample sizes

Tags: python, scipy, statistics, analysis

I have this task:

1. Choose your favorite continuous distribution (the less it looks normal, the more interesting; try to choose one of the distributions we have not discussed in the course).

   2. Generate a sample of 1000 from it, build a histogram of the sample,
      and draw a theoretical density of distribution of your random value
      on top of it (so that the values are on the same scale, don't forget
      to set the histogram to normed=True). Your task is to estimate the
      distribution of your random sample average for different sample
      sizes.

3
 To do this, generate 1000 samples of n volume and build
    histograms of their sample averages for three or more n values (for
    example, 5, 10, 50).

4. Using the information on the mean and
   variance of the original distribution (easily found on wikipedia),
   calculate the values of the normal distribution parameters, which,
   according to the central limit theorem, approximate the distribution
   of the sample averages. Note: to calculate the values of these
   parameters, it is the theoretical mean and the variance of your
   random value that should be used, and not their sample estimates.

5.
    On top of each histogram, draw the density of the corresponding
    normal distribution (be careful with the parameters of the function,
    it takes the input not the dispersion, but the standard deviation).

6. Describe the difference between the distributions obtained at different n values. How 
   does the accuracy of the approximation of
   the distribution of sample averages change with the growth of n?

So if I want to pick exponential distribution in Python do I need to go like that?

```
from scipy.stats import expon
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

exdist=sc.expon(loc=2,scale=3) # loc and scale - shift and scale parameters, default values 0 and 1.
mean, var, skew, kurt = exdist.stats(moments='mvsk') # Let's see the moments of our distribution.
x = np.linspace((0,2,100))
ax.plot(x, exdist.pdf(x)) # Let's draw it
arr=exdist.rvc(size=1000) # generation of thousand of random numbers. (Is it for task 3?)
```

And I constantly getting this error: here is a screenshot from Jupyter:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwUtu.png
Could you please explain to me how to write the right code? I can't figure out where to start or where to make a mistake. Do I have to use arr.mean() to search for a sample mean and plt.hist(arr,bins=) to build a histogram? I would be very grateful for the explanation.

Comment: Try importing like this: `from scipy.stats import expon` then `expon(loc=2, scale=3)`

Comment: Now I am getting a message: 'name ax is not defined' how to solve this?